# How do I create a Razor view to capture a certain content type in Umbraco?

Tags: razor, content-management-system, umbraco

All the documentation I have found, and that is lots, shows how to create a content type, capture documents of that content type using the Umbraco UI, and how to create templates to display that document.

I'm sure I need a POST action, which will get a view model reflecting the content type structure; it's variables and other content, but where to find this and what to do with the data remain a mystery to me.

How do I create a document capture view, as well as the so common display view?

Comment: Are you asking how to create a form that will be used to create a new instance of a content type?

Comment: Yes, I am asking that. All I've been able to find is stuff on how to build templates for display, maybe with capture fields, but not how to actually create an instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly easy to create a form that POSTs to a surface controller. There is a very good tutorial in the Our Umbraco community website which may be useful to you. You can find the tutorial [here](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Mvc/forms).

Inside the controller action that handles the POST, you need to add a call to the Umbraco Management API, which is used for CRUD operations.

Here's an example of how to create and populate the properties of a content document in Umbraco 6+:

```
private void AddProduct(int productId, string name, int productGroupId, int price)
    {
        // Get the Umbraco Content Service
        var contentService = Services.ContentService;

        var product = contentService.CreateContent(
            name,           // the name of the product document
            productGroupId, // the parent id should be the id of the group node 
            "product",      // the alias of the product Document Type
            0);

        // Here's how to update some of the properties
        product.SetValue("productId", productId);
        product.SetValue("originalName", name);
        product.SetValue("priceDKK", price);

        // finally we need to save and publish, this saves the product and the property values
        contentService.SaveAndPublish(product);
}
```

There are similar services for Media, Files, DataTypes etc. For more info, have a look [here](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Management-v6/Services/ContentService) for Umbraco v6+ and [here](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Management/) for earlier versions.

Comment: I can see no example of how to actually persist the document in that tutorial. It just returns a success message, but how does the form get to the DB? That's what I meant my the documentation being inadequate.

Comment: OK, now I get what you're trying to find. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: `name`, `parentId` etc. describing the content type? Does the instance data, e.g. `bodyText` get automatically extracted?

Comment: I've updated the example to show how you would populate the document properties. Name and parentId will describe the IContent (document) instance, if you want to programmatically add a new content type, there is a different service you would have to call.

Comment: Thanks. None of the examples I've on the Umbraco site do anything meaningful inside the controllers.

Comment: You're right, they could at least have added a link to the Management API page for reference. Did my answer help you? Where you able to save the form data to Umbraco?

Comment: I will only be able to try later today. Where does one place such code, i.e. the controllers, service client code such as your example, etc?

Comment: The convention is to put all controllers in the Controllers folder. If the service code is simple and it usually is, just leave it inside the Action. Being consistent with the conventions across projects matters in terms of maintenability of the code within a team, but if it's just you, it's only a matter of preference.